# Kill and Load function based on different screen size javascript

Tags: javascript

I have code like:

```
function interactionScreen(){
   if ($(window).width() > 970) {  
      do something..
   } else if ($(window).width() < 970) {  
      do something..
   }
}

interactionScreen();   

$(window).resize(function() {
   interactionScreen();  
});
```

What I would like to achieve is that when the browser is resize to less than 970 then it will run other code. The issue is that when the page is load, script under > 970 will run first, if i resize the browser, both script > 970 and < 970 are run, just wondering if is there anyway to "destroy" the script and rerun the function?

Comment: You need to "undo" all the things you do in your function - eg if you resize something, the resize it back to it's original size, if you bind an event, then unbind it, etc

Answer (score -1):

You could wait until the browser window hasn't changed its size for at least x milliseconds before executing your function

```
var interactionScreen = (function(window) {
    var timer,
        w = $(window);

    return function(executeImmediately) {
        clearTimeout(timer);

        timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    var currentWidth = w.width();

                    if (currentWidth > 970) {
                        console.log("> 970");
                    } else {
                        console.log("<= 970");
                    }
                }, executeImmediately ? 0 : 200);
    };
}(window));

interactionScreen(true);

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    interactionScreen();
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ptk5a8b9/)